# Derivative of Hadamard product with kernels

Tags: derivatives, hadamard-product

I want to calculate
$$ \frac{\partial(A \circ X^\top X)}{\partial(X)}, $$
where $ \circ $ is Hadamard product (elementwise product),
$X \in R^{r \times n}$, $A \in R^{n \times n}$, and $\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}=0$.

So far, I found that
$$ \frac{\partial(A \circ B)}{\partial(C)} = \frac{\partial(A)}{\partial(C)} \circ B + A \circ \frac{\partial(B)}{\partial(C)},$$
from here ([generic rule matrix differentiation (Hadamard Product, element-wise)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130251/generic-rule-matrix-differentiation-hadamard-product-element-wise))

In my case, $B=X^\top X$ and $C=X$.

Therefore,
$$ \frac{\partial(A \circ X^\top X)}{\partial(X)} = A \circ 2X^\top .$$

However, $A\in R^{n\times n}$ and $X^\top \in R^{n \times r}$.

Therefore, I can't do the Hadamard product.

How can I do this?

Comment: the problem is in your derivative of $X^T X$ for a *rectangular* matrix (as far as I'm aware, it is not equal to $2X^T$) (see also: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First we'll need a few tensors.

A 6th-order tensor ${\mathbb M}$, whose components ${\mathbb M}_{ijklmn}$ are unity if $\,(i=k=m)$ and $(j=l=n),\,$ but zero otherwise.

This tensor makes it possible to rewrite a Hadamard ($\circ$) product using Frobenius (:) products like so
$$\eqalign{
A\circ Z &= A:{\mathbb M}:Z \cr\cr
}$$

Next we'll need two 4th-order isotropic tensors whose components are
$$\eqalign{
{\mathbb E}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl} \cr
{\mathbb B}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{il}\,\delta_{jk} \cr
}$$
These tensors make it possible to re-arrange matrix products
$$\eqalign{
A\,dX\,Z &= A{\mathbb E}Z^T:dX \cr
A\,dX^T\,Z &= A{\mathbb E}Z^T:{\mathbb B}:dX \cr\cr
}$$

Now we are ready to find the differential and gradient of your function 
$$\eqalign{
  F &= A\circ X^TX \cr &= A:{\mathbb M}:X^TX \cr\cr
 dF &= A:{\mathbb M}:(dX^TX+X^TdX) \cr
    &= A:{\mathbb M}:({\mathbb E}X^T:{\mathbb B}:dX+X^T{\mathbb E}:dX) \cr
    &= A:{\mathbb M}:{\mathbb E}X^T:{\mathbb B}:dX + A:{\mathbb M}:X^T{\mathbb E}:dX \cr
    &= A:{\mathbb M}:\big({\mathbb E}X^T:{\mathbb B}\,\,+\,\,X^T{\mathbb E}\big):dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial F}{\partial X} &= A:{\mathbb M}:\Big({\mathbb E}X^T:{\mathbb B} \,+\, X^T{\mathbb E}\Big) \cr\cr\cr
}$$
Another approach is to use vectorization.
Let
$$\eqalign{
  f &= \operatorname{vec}(F) \cr
  x &= \operatorname{vec}(X) \cr
  a &= \operatorname{vec}(A) \cr
  {\mathcal A} &= \operatorname{Diag}(a) \cr
}$$
Then
$$\eqalign{
 df &= a\circ\operatorname{vec}(dX^TX+X^TdX) \cr
    &= {\mathcal A}\,\Big((X^T\otimes I)B\,dx + (I\otimes X^T)\,dx \Big) \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= {\mathcal A}\,(X^T\otimes I)B\,+\,{\mathcal A}\,(I\otimes X^T) \cr
}$$where $B$ is the [Kronecker Commutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307299/kronecker-product-and-the-commutation-matrix) matrix.

This is actually quite similar to the tensor result, with 
$$\eqalign{
 {\mathcal A} &\sim A:{\mathbb M} \cr
 (X^T\otimes I)B &\sim I\,{\mathbb E}\,X^T:{\mathbb B} \cr
 (I\otimes X^T) &\sim X^T{\mathbb E}\,I \cr
}$$

Comment: can you recommend some material to study what you show to us? @greg