# Matrix derivative over non-scalar function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, multivalued-functions

I'm attempting to obtain a derivative for the following function by matrix $U$:

$$R = \sum_{i=1}^n||ƒ(s ⋅ U) ⋅ V ⋅ M_i - f(t ⋅ U) ⋅ V|| ^ 2$$

where $s \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times3}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times3}$, $U \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$, $V \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$, $M_i \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$

I wish to use the derivative for the gradient descent method.

Now when $f$ is scalar function ie. $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} $ there is no issue with evaluating derivative:

suppose that:
$$g = ƒ(s ⋅ U) ⋅ V ⋅ M_i - f(t ⋅ U) ⋅ V$$

then:

$$\frac{\partial{R}}{\partial{U}} = 2\sum_{i=1}^ns^T \cdot ((g \cdot (V \cdot M_i)^T) ∘ \frac{\partial f}{\partial{U}}(s \cdot U)) - t^T \cdot ((g \cdot V^T) ∘ \frac{\partial f}{\partial{U}}(t \cdot U))$$

But when $f$ becomes a function of vector argument $f:\mathbb{R}^{1\times3}\to\mathbb{R}^{1x3}$ i.e. $f$ accepts a vector-row and results with vector row. In this case the derivative of $f$ becomes a Jacobian of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ and it becomes unclear on how to evaluate the Hadamard product with vector-row of size $\mathbb{R}^{1\times3}$ on the left hand side and  $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ Jacobian.

I cant wrap my head around this problem for a week already, can anyone aid me with some thoughts on the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change $\,(s,t)\,$ into column vectors
and define these additional vectors
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\D#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\f{f^\prime}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=1}^m}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^n}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
a &= f(U^Ts),\quad A=\D{\f(U^Ts)} &\qiq &da = A\;dU^Ts \\
b &= f(U^Tt),\quad B=\D{\f(U^Tt)} &\qiq &db = B\;dU^Tt \\
g_k &= M_k^T V^Ta - V^T b &\qiq &dg_k = M_k^T V^Tda - V^Tdb \\
q &= \Sk g_k,\quad r = \Sk M_kg_k \\
}$$
where $\f(z)$ denotes the ordinary derivative of the scalar function $f(z),$ and both functions are applied **element-wise** when given vector arguments.

The $\D{v}$ function creates a diagonal matrix from its vector argument, and this diagonal matrix can replace elementwise/Hadamard products involving the vector
$$v\odot w =\D{v}\,w$$
Use these new variables to rewrite the objective function
and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\R{{\cal R}}
\R &= \Sk g_k : g_k \\
d\R &= \Sk 2g_k : dg_k \\
 &= 2\Sk\BR{g_k:M_k^T V^Tda \;-\; g_k:V^Tdb} \\
 &= 2\Sk\BR{VM_kg_k:da \;-\; Vg_k:db} \\
 &= 2\BR{Vr:da \;-\; Vq:db} \\
 &= 2Vr:\LR{A\;dU^Ts} \;-\; 2Vq:\LR{B\;dU^Tt} \\
 &= 2AVrs^T:dU^T \;-\; 2BVqt^T:dU^T \\
 &= 2sr^TV^TA:dU \;-\; 2tq^TV^TB:dU \\
 &= 2\BR{sr^TV^TA - tq^TV^TB} : dU \\
\frac{\p\R}{\p U}
 &= 2\BR{sr^TV^TA - tq^TV^TB} \\
\\
}$$

---

In the above derivation, the symbol $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= \Sj\Sk X_{jk}Y_{jk} \;=\; {\rm trace}\!\LR{X^TY} \\
X:X &= \|X\|_F^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
}$$
When applied to vectors $(m=\o{\;\rm or\;}n=\o)$ it corresponds to the dot product.

The terms in such products can be rearranged in many useful ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= Y:X \;=\; Y^T:X^T \\
X:\LR{YZ} &= \LR{XZ^T}:Y \;=\; \LR{Y^TX}:Z \\
}$$

Comment: I have just one question, how did you came to this neat thought? I mean the fact that you can use $Diag(f'(U^T . s))$ ? @greg

Comment: @Lu4 I didn't invent it, I just read it somewhere.  Once you've seen the $\,a\odot b={\rm Diag}(a)\:b\,$ substitution, you don't forget it since it's extremely useful. A [similar substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2061982/357854) exists for the Hadamard product of a matrix, but it involves tensors so it's used less often.