# Derivatives involving inner product and Hadamard product

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, gradient-descent, hadamard-product

Let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I am trying to compute

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x\circ y)^Tz\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x\circ y)^T(x \circ y)
$$

where $x\circ y$ is the Hadamard product of $x$ and $y$, but it is throwing me for a loop. Can someone show me how to proceed with these derivatives?

Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1547923/389740), it appears that I can write $f(x,y)=(x\circ y)^T(x\circ y) = (x\circ y)^TI(x\circ y)$ and thus

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y\circ (I^T+I)(x\circ y)
$$
but I am confused about the first part, $y\circ(I^T+I)$. The dimensions do not seem to match up properly since $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $I\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

---

Context: I would like to compute the gradient of the following:

$$
\begin{split}
||x-\alpha\circ y||_2^2 &= (x-\alpha\circ y)^T(x-\alpha\circ y)\\
& = x^Tx - x^T(\alpha\circ y) - (\alpha\circ y)^Tx + (\alpha\circ y)^T(\alpha\circ y)
\end{split}
$$

with respect to $\alpha$ as part of the derivation of a gradient descent update. If there is  a simpler way to compute the derivative of this 2-norm, please share; however, I'd still like to know how to compute the individual derivatives as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elementwise/Hadamard product $\,(A\circ B)\,$ and the inner/Frobenius product $\,(A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB))\,$ are mutually commutative, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
 A\circ B &= B\circ A \cr
 A:B &= B:A \cr
 A\circ B:C &= A:B\circ C \cr
}$$ These products are defined for matrices of *any* shape (including vectors), as long as $\{A,B,C\}$ have the *same* shape

Applying these rules to your first function
$$\eqalign{
 f &= z:x\circ y  = z\circ y:x \cr
df &= z\circ y:dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= z\circ y \cr\cr
}$$
For your second function, let $z=x\circ y$
$$\eqalign{
 g &= z:z \cr
dg &= 2z:dz = 2z:y\circ dx = 2z\circ y:dx \cr
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= 2z\circ y = 2x\circ y\circ y \cr\cr
}$$
Your final function is very similar to the second. This time set $z=(a\circ y-x)$
$$\eqalign{
 h &= z:z \cr
dh &= 2z:dz = 2z:y\circ da = 2z\circ y:da \cr
\frac{\partial h}{\partial a} &= 2z\circ y = 2(a\circ y-x)\circ y \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: Do you have any references where I can go to learn these rules? I need to compute something similar so it would be great to find something to explain the theory, how it works in practice, and provide some problems.