# derivative of function of a matrix

Tags: calculus, matrix-calculus

Assume $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, we want to find the derivative of $f(A(X \circ X)) \in \mathbb{R}$ over $X$.

I think $\nabla_{X}f(A(X \circ X)) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, but $\nabla_X f(A(X \circ X)) = \nabla_{A(X \circ X)}f(A(X \circ X)) \frac{d A(X \circ X)}{d X}$, where $\nabla_{AX}f(AX) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$,
where $(X \circ X) = X_{ij}^2$.

I am confused how to calculate $\frac{d A(X \circ X)}{d X}$ and what is the dimension of it such that $\nabla_{X}f(A(X \circ X)) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$.

According to [generic rule matrix differentiation (Hadamard Product, element-wise)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130251/generic-rule-matrix-differentiation-hadamard-product-element-wise), it seems I can get
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  d f(A(X\circ X)) 
& = \nabla_{A(X\circ X)}f: d(A(X\circ X)) \\
& = A^T (\nabla_{A(X\circ X)}f):d(X\circ X) \\
& = A^T (\nabla_{A(X\circ X)}f):2X \circ dX \\
& = A^T (\nabla_{A(X\circ X)}f) \circ 2X dX \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$
$$
I am not sure if the last equation hold since I have no idea to deal with $2X \circ dX$.

Comment: Let $G=\nabla f\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times r}$, then so far you have
$$df = (A^TG):(2X\circ dX)$$
To finish it off, simply move the Hadamard product to the LHS and leave $dX$ on the RHS. 
$$\eqalign{
df &= \Big(2X\circ(A^TG)\Big):dX \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= \Big(2X\circ(A^TG)\Big) \\
}$$